# Simple python multithreading shared variable

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have a simple project where I display messages one letter at a time using a LED strip with my rpi. Sometimes LEDs will randomly light up and get stuck until it gets cleared when displaying a new message.

My solution is to create another thread to clear the strip once every ~2 seconds, so if LEDs do randomly turn on they will be quickly turned off again.

I obviously don't want that thread to be clearing the display while a message is displaying, so I created a global variable to track whether or not a message is currently being displayed.

here's a stripped down version of the relevant code:

```
displaying = False


def display(msg):
    global displaying
    displaying = True
    for c in msg:
        turn_all_leds_off()
        display_char(c)
        time.sleep(1)
        turn_all_leds_off()
        time.sleep(.2)
    time.sleep(1)
    displaying = False


def listen_on_client():
    while True:
        global displaying
        if not displaying:
            get_new_messages_from_server_and_display_them()
        time.sleep(2)


def clear_errors():
    while True:
        global displaying
        if not displaying:
            display(" ")
        time.sleep(2)


t1 = Thread(target=listen_on_client, args=())
t2 = Thread(target=clear_errors, args=())
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

the problem is, the displaying variable doesn't seem to work. The program behaves as if displaying is always false when the error clearing thread checks it. I'm used to having to use locks in other programing languages when I need to worry about race conditions, but honestly I just need this to work on the order of seconds, not nanoseconds. It's not a race condition, it seems that the variable is cached on each thread and python doesn't have a volatile keyword. This is similar to how other SO questions have suggested doing it so I'm not quite sure what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the global declared inside the while loops to hopefully avoid any caching but that seemed to actually have the opposite effect.

changing everything from

```
def clear_errors():
    while True:
        global displaying
```

to

```
def clear_errors():
    global displaying
    while True:
```

fixed it. Not sure why though.